# C++ destructor of a class containing a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, destructor, stdvector

I have a class that looks like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    vector<int*> V;

public:
    MyClass();        
    MyClass(int n);
    ~MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{             
    return;
}

MyClass::MyClass(int n)
{
    int* T = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        T[i]=i;
        V.push_back(&(T[i]));
    }
    return;
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    for(int i =0; i<V.size(); i++)
        delete V[i];
    return;
}

int main()
{   
    MyClass C(5);
    return 0;
}
```

1. What's wrong about my destructor? I get a "*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer:..." error upon execution of this.
2. Do you think I should use ptr_vector? I don't know if I have the courage to learn about those.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're violating the rule of three. It's not the problem in this program, but it will cause problems.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you can't use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` and eliminate direct use of dynamic allocation?

Comment: Your constructor makes no sense.  You're allocating an array T, but for no apparent purpose, and then storing invalid pointer values into your vector, then trying to delete each element of your vector as though it were a pointer.  There's little to nothing correct or sensible here

Comment: If you're ok with using `vector<int*>` to store a list of arrays, why not just use a `vector<vector<int>>` and save yourself a whole load of issues, that completely removes the need for a destructor and simplifies hidden problems with copy constructors.

Comment: Okay, after having posted my answer, and reading the other answers, I have come to a new conclusion: all of them are equally right/wrong, because this code makes so little sense. How about you rephrase your question to also include in english wat you WANT to achieve?

Comment: Agreed. If a vector of pointers is just your solution to a bigger problem, post that, as there's a good chance there's a better option.

Comment: Okay guys, I agree that it's impossible to understand what I want to achieve from what I posted, but I didn't mean to tell you what I want to achieve, I just wanted to know what's wrong with this code and I got my answer, thanks again to you all. The thing is, I could tell you more but what I want to do is complicated and I don't really see the point. The important thing is, I have to work with a class that has an attribute vector<someotherclass*>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your destructor, you're deleting pointers that were never allocated. You can only use `delete` (or `delete[]`) if there's a specific matching use of `new` (or `new[]`), and for n-1 of your `int` pointers, there is no such call.

If you want your vector to hold pointers to individual unrelated `int`s, then you need to use `new` to allocate each one individually. If they're always going to be in an array like this, then keep a pointer to that array in a member, and delete just that one pointer in your destructor.

Comment: I see, so if I understand correctly you agree with the answer of Yuri?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Your intention is to have a vector of pointers, not arrays, so the problem is with your constructor:

```
int* T = new int[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   T[i]=i;
   V.push_back(&(T[i]));
}
```

This doesn't create `n` pointers, but a pointer to `n` `int`s.
You should do:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    V.push_back(new int(i));
}
```

Before edit:

The problem isn't *only* in the destructor, but the constructor.

I'm assuming you want to push the array in the vector, in which case you need:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int n)
{
    int* T = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        T[i]=i;
    }
    V.push_back(T);
    return;
}
```

You're also getting undefined behavior by calling

```
delete V[i];
```

instead of

```
delete[] V[i];
```

Comment: @user1367124, what reason do you have for making the vector contain pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a contiguous block of memory with

```
int *T = new int[n];
```

You cannot delete single elements of this block. You can only delete the entire block at once.

Comment: Really? That sounds weird to me.  How do I write the destructor of a class which contains a vector<someotherclass*>, maybe the vector's entries point to objects that happen to be in arrays?

Comment: @Benj He is allocating a block of N elements, let's say T has addresses 100 to 110. Then he inserts those addresses into a vector, and on destruction he calls `delete V[i]`, i.e. `delete 100; delete 101,...delete 110`.